# angularjs duplicating controllers/displaying same data in multiple spots

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have 2 separate parts of the DOM that I want to show the same data. eg: count of new messages. However I do not want to call the service (ajax request) for each controller.

Originally I had used the same controller (ng-controller="totalMessages") in the 2 different containing spams and that worked, but the console showed the ajax request being called twice.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
   ......
   <div ng-controller="totalMessages">
    <span ng-bind="totalMsg">0</span>
   </div>
   ......
   <div ng-controller="totalMessages">
    There are <span ng-bind="totalMsg">0</span> new messages.
   </div>
   ......
</body>
```

An example of the view.

How is it best to achieve this without making multiple ajax requests?

ps.I am new to angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Option 1 - Use the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory) provided by ng to cache the values. But these does not provide any control over how the data will be retreived. You have to implement your own logic to look for the data in cache first and if not present make an ajax request.
2. Option 2 - Enable cache in [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http). Still this provides less control over the underlying cache mechanism. Incase if cache has to be enabled for only the specific request then this will require some more additional logic
3. Option 3 - Use a custom service to fetch the data like the sample below. Though this looks like extra bit of logic it will provide you more control to the message. For instance in case if you want to refresh the message after an hour, you can simple include modified date and set a timeout to check whether the last refreshed time is greater than an hour and refresh the message.

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.service('msgService',function(){
  var message = 0, msgLoaded = false;
  this.getMsg = function(){
    if(!msgLoaded){
      //include the ajax request to get the message here.
      message++;
      msgLoaded = true;
    }
    return message;
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, msgService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.message = msgService.getMsg();
});
```

A Sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qIVOcaIYkbMCzEYpoWnR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

An option is an underlying Angular service that will hide the calls to the actual web/REST service. The Angular service will also handle caching of the data, so that even though both controllers will call it, the actual remote call will happen only once. Let the method of the Angular service return a promise that will get resolved either with the data from the remote call, or with the cached data.

Comment: Thanks. I had thought about caching, but not sure how that will work as this controller will eventually need to be repeated (every 30 seconds) to check for new messages. eg. setTimeout or the angular equivalent.

Comment: The service can implement the caching and timeout policies, again hiding this detail from its consumers. So, in this case, the controllers repeat their call to the *Angular* service as frequently as they want; the service decides whether its cache is valid at each given time, so as to return it (the cache) or call the remote service instead.